# Why is my local drive are mounted has root?

Tags: permissions, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL to work on web project, and it's causing me a lot of problem that everything is owned by root instead of the actual user. Is there a way to change that behavior ? If yes, will that have any impact ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the right way on a microsoft devblog post, I share it for future me and future you!

**Long answer:**

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

**Quick answer:**

Get your UID:
`id -u username`

Get your GID:
`id -g username`

Unmount actual C drive (can be replaced by the letter of your choice):
`sudo umount /mnt/c`

Mount back with the right permission:
`sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata,uid=<YOUR UID>,gid=<YOUR GID>`